# Custom Floating Action Button with background and text

Tags: android, text, floating-action-button

I want create a my custom fab. This fab must be 270 long and 45 high. I want apply ( I have it ) a drawable for round and set background. In other I want set text of fab at center of this. Anyone can help me?

[image: The result should be this but it is a textView, now I want do this with floating action button]

Thanks!

Comment: May I ask why do you need a floating button for this? What discourages you about not using a normal button instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_my_icon"
    android:layout_margin="16dp" />
```

where the icon is a new image asset with your text. In android studio go to your drawable folder and right click->new->Image Asset, under Asset Type, select text and type in your text. save your icon and add it to the xml above as shown

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        />
```